# Plugin enabling live previewing of the colour schemes

Tags: colorscheme, previewing

I am a vim newbie and some time ago I installed a plugin that enables previewing color schemes by repeatedly pressing a key. It is not the `colorscheme` command which lists the schemes and switches to text in the editor after you select it.

This one I am talking about actually switches the scheme in use when you press the cycling key, more like a live preview, and you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key if you find the one you want, or <kbd>escape</kbd> to cancel to retain the current scheme.

Can anyone tell me the name of the plugin?

Comment: 1. [vim-thematic](https://github.com/reedes/vim-thematic) does more than that, but allows moving to the next "theme" with `<leader>T`. 2. [unite-colorscheme](https://github.com/ujihisa/unite-colorscheme) is a colorscheme source for the [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) plugin, and AFAIK you can use it with a preview.

Comment: [ScrollColors](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1488)? There is even [a video](http://youtu.be/FLRA3G-ltGY).

Comment: @VanLaser what is <leader>T? I am afraid my knowledge of Vim is rather sketchy although I remember learning `vi` some time in the late 80s. I'll try your suggestions as well.

Comment: I checked my plugin folder and both ScrollColors and vim-colorschemes are there so I suspect that vim-colorschemes may have overridden ScrollColors settings.

Comment: vim-colorschemes is just a collection of color schemes, it shouldn't override anything. Try running `:SCROLLCOLOR`.

Comment: @vfclists Run `:h <Leader>` from Vim - it's nothing too special, just a key you can set to be run as prefix (by default it should be backslash). Honestly, try to read some Vim tutorials before focusing too much on the colorschemes :)

Comment: I switched to `vim` from `nano` as the basic editor in the console and the default scheme which displays comments in blue against the black background is maddening. Is there a way to list all the plugins installed and check if they are working properly? ScrollColors is installed but the preview function doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331956/6253165